# How to get HTTP response with AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: php, ios, json, afnetworking, afjsonrequestoperation

Sending json data to server and want to get correct  response.statusCode from server with `AFNetworking`

server:

```
// Helper method to send a HTTP response code/message
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'text/html')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
} 
sendResponse(200, json_encode("Files Deleted"));
```

IOS:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:server];
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
        // don't forget to set parameterEncoding!
        httpClient.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding;\
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:deleteExtraFilesIn parameters:nil];
        [request setHTTPBody:[displayJson  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request addValue:@"ASIHTTPRequest" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
        [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        NSLog(@"request %@",request);
        [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];

        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
            // Print the response body in text
            if (operation.response.statusCode == 200) {
                NSLog(@"Got you");

            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
        [operation start];
```

ERROR NSLOG:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x1f519df0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

How can I get correct http response in above code?

Note:`json_encode("Files Deleted")` on server is just dummy text what I want is http response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the operation to allow fragments:

```
        AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];
operation.JSONReadingOptions = NSJSONReadingAllowFragments;
```

Comment: xcode says property 'JSONReadingoptios' not found on object of type 'AFHTTPRequestOperation', what class does it belong to?

Comment: You just need to not store the instance as a AFHTTPRequestOperation, store it as the true AFJSONRequestOperation that it is.